# How to close or cancel custom alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I tried closing the `AlertDialog` when cancel button is clicked, but it is not working. I tried using `.dismiss()` and `.cancel()` but none of them works.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
  final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                        final View viewer = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_dialog, null);

                        alertDialog.setTitle("Edit Albums Name");
                        alertDialog.setView(viewer);

                        Button send =(Button) viewer.findViewById(R.id.saveAlBtn);
                        Button cancel =(Button) viewer.findViewById(R.id.dismissBtn);


      final AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();

                            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.cancel(); // dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Are you sure the button with the id `dismissBtn` is the right button? Maybe you copied it in the xml and forgot to change the id or something. Also, when do you call `dialog.show()`?

Comment: @Gumbo Im calling the alertDialog.show() ?? Yes the Im referencing it to the right button id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is a simple, but tricky one: 
You create a `AlertDialog` from the builder and call it `dialog`. When the cancel button is clicked, you close the `dialog`. But you have never actually shown the dialog, i.e. called `dialog.show()`, but instead called the `show()` method of the `Builder` which is called `alertDialog`. That method creates and shows the dialog in one step, but it creates a new instance, which you don't give a name to, and thus can't close anymore.

You either need to call `dialog.show()` instead of `alertDialog.show()` or use `AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.show()` and remove the second `alertDialog.show()` completely.